# How to display single row as multiple row from database to gridview?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

How to display single row that has multiple values as a multiple row in gridview from database?

Example:

**Database row with values - also my gridview result**

[image]

Id of both orders is : 1

**What the result needs to be:**

[image]

id of both orders is : 1

**What i have so far**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mk"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT bookName, numOfItems, category, FROM [Orders]))
{
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        gw1.DataSource = dt;
        gw1.DataBind();                        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
}
```

**update**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mk"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT bookName, numOfItems, category FROM [Order]"))
                {
                    var newdt= dt.Clone();
                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            var bookNames= row.Field<string>("bookName").Split(',');
                            var numOfItems= row.Field<string>("numOfItems").Split(',');
                            var categorys= row.Field<string>("category").Split(',');
                            //assume all columns having asme number of items seperated by comma 
                            for (int i = 0; i < bookNames.Length; i++)
                            {
                                var newRow = newdt.Rows.Add();
                                newRow.SetField("bookName", bookNames[i]);
                                newRow.SetField("numOfItems", numOfItems[i]);
                                newRow.SetField("category", categorys[i]);
                            }
                        }

                        gw1.DataSource = newdt;
                        gw1.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I'd suggest having different id's for each row in your database. This would prevent the issue from occurring in the first place.

Comment: cannot have different id's because i have multiple forms. by multiple forms i mean, user can add as many books as possible, and all that is on button click which loads new form @Bas

Comment: If I get this correctly, you'll need a many to many relation. Create an additional table in your database which contains 2 ids, one from the user and one from your book. That way your users can have multiple books, and your books will still have separate ids. If this isn't correct, I would strongly suggest rethinking your database structure.

Comment: well does it matter? when app runs and user inputs data, it all still gets inserted into one row, no matter how many forms @Bas

Comment: well seeing that you are running into problems, I would say yes. It just makes it easier to store and retrieve data. I can only suggest doing it, it's up to you to design your database.

Comment: i have 2 tables - orders and customers. you are suggesting table number 3? @Bas

Comment: Yes. Take a look at this article if you have more questions about many to many relations: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mk"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT bookName, numOfItems, category FROM [Order]"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        var newdt= dt.Clone();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            var bookNames= row.Field<string>("bookName").Split(',');
            var numOfItems= row.Field<string>("numOfItems").Split(',');
            var categorys= row.Field<string>("category").Split(',');
            //assume all columns having asme number of items seperated by comma 
            for (int i = 0; i < bookNames.Length; i++)
            {
                var newRow = newdt.Rows.Add();
                newRow.SetField("bookName", bookNames[i]);
                newRow.SetField("numOfItems", numOfItems[i]);
                newRow.SetField("category", categorys[i]);
            }
        }

        gw1.DataSource = newdt;
        gw1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `gw1.DataSource = dt;  gw1.DataBind(); ` with above

Comment: can you look at update ans see if that's it. because if that's it....well gridview doesn't even show up